# Communicating with a Wordpress database

Tags: php, database, wordpress

This question is a bit wider than accepted on SO, but I need to start somewhere as I am a bit new to some things.

I am developing an iOS/Android app for a client who has an online store based on Wordpress.

Inside the app, the user logs in using their user credentials that he/she has created on the online store, where the underlying login system is handled using webrequests

His WP site has a database called `store_locations` consisting of `longitude` and `latitude` fields, and I need to somehow read the fields from the app.

What I am wondering is:

1. would I need to create a custom PHP script to access the DB?
2. How is security handled such as user verification?
3. Where is the PHP script placed on the server?

**NOTE:**

> Please let's have a discussion in the comments first, as I might need
>   to fine-tune the question as per request if anything is unclear.

**EDIT 1**
I found the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7ID_L91lIk
where the instructor at `19:00 to 20:51`  talks about what I'm assuming would clarify `question 2` from above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to interact with Wordpress from an external source you should use [WordPress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

You need to fetch data from a custom database table, so take a look at [Adding custom endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this is probably too broad for here.  I suggest you create a plugin that gives you ajax access.  You can study up on that [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and then when you have more specific questions, let us know.

I understand that you asked to discuss it in the comments first, but there is just not enough to discuss here and that is asking quite a lot for an undeveloped plan.

If you have more questions, feel free to comment here.

Comment: Is what this man is doing something in the right direction? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7ID_L91lIk